# Disabling JSHint for CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript, sublimetext2, jshint

I recently installed JSHint via Package Manager in Sublime Text 2. As part of my job, I need to edit .coffee files, which JSHint throws all kinds of errors on. I'm unable to identify any preference files or other means of disabling JSHint on these files.

Is it possible to selectively disable JSHint on certain file extensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `.jshintignore` file at the top level with this in it:

```
*.coffee
```